# Does at scheduled tasks remain after reboot?

Tags: at

I'm using `at` to schedule a task for a later time.

Will it survive a reboot, or should I re-assign all the tasks after reboot ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to be the case, the `at` action will be preserved after reboot, as answered [here](https://serverfault.com/a/12864/143680).

> Yes they are persistent across reboots (they're just files in a spool).

Files used by `at` as detailed in the man page:

```
/var/spool/at
```

When you schedule an action, it will be stored in a file in `/var/spool/at/<action_file>`