# What happened to a sleep command after server shutdown?

Tags: linux, reboot, sleep

I would like to execute a script after 5 hours. My script is

```
$cat << EOF > run.sh
sleep 18000
sh run_my_script.sh
EOF
```

I submitted the job as:

```
sh run.sh >& log &
```

But due to some problem the server got shutdown.

My question is what will happen to my job:

```
1- Whether my job got deleted and I will have to submit the job again?
2- Server reboot within 5 hours. Will job still valid and start at 5 hours?
3- Server reboot after 5 hours.
```

Comment: Are you running the 2 commands from a shell prompt?

Comment: No, these commands are inside another script e.g. "run.sh". I have edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: Strange question because on shutdown all procceses are gone. Jobs is a shell feature so when your shell process is gone all jobs are gone too.

Answer (score 2):

1- if the job gets deleted, you will have to submit job again. The sleep command will be killed so how much time elapsed will be lost

2- If servers gets rebooted before 18000 seconds have passed, job will be invalid

3- `run_my_script.sh` will run in this case

Consider using cron

Comment: You can simulate the 3 scenarios yourself by using a smaller timeframe, like a few minutes instead of 5 hours

Comment: The `3-run_my_script.sh will run in this case` is not clear. If it will run, then how job will be invalid  if server reboot before 5 hours. I can check it in my own linux system. But my question was for remote hpc.

Comment: I assumed server reboot after 5 hours means it will run more than 5 hours. Anyway, if you mean server will reboot exactly after 5 hours, the sleep command will complete and the `sh run_my_script.sh` may get a chance to run before the server reboots. But it may not. (As mentioned, use cron, or at)

Answer (score 2):

The `sleep` command will get killed on shutdown.

You should use `at` which will [survive a reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256748/does-at-scheduled-tasks-remain-after-reboot).

e.g.

```bash
echo "sh run_my_script.sh" | at now+5hours
```